# Sort members in Class Diagrams in VS 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I want to show the members of my classes grouped by type and in the same order as they are defined in code, but they are always shown in alphabetical order. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I doubt it but what exactly do you mean by `as they are defined in code`? Project structure? In the code file? Something else?

Comment: yes, I want to keep the same order as they are defined in the code file, which is a logical order

Comment: That is not possible.

Comment: I assumed, but just in case you could. In my case I set a logical order in my code and it would be useful if I can keep that order in the class view and in the class diagram. Thanks for you quick answer.

Comment: Facing the same issue as for me the order of items in an enum matter.